# How do I plot an interaction graph, like a schemaball, from a table showing correlation/interaction data in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, networkx

I've got a table with data from which I'd like to show the interaction in an informative way.
I have counted the interactions between different people, and inputted this in a table, which looks like this:

[image: Table showing interactions between people]

ideally, I'd like to visualise this data in interesting ways (if you know more, please let me know!). I found these things, and I'd like to create one from this data myself.

[image: Simpsons interaction graph]

I found some tutorials online, however, I can't seem to get it to work as I am unable to input my data the right way in an NX graph: when iterating through the table, I end up attaching wrong ends to eachother or skipping data.

data:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2 | x | 0 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | x | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| D | 3 | 4 | 3 | x | 1 | 1 |
| E | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | x | 1 |
| F | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | x |

Best-Effort code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib

namelist = []
for i in range(0,len(systeem)):
    namelist.append(systeem.iloc[i,0])

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(namelist)

weightlist=[]
for i in range(0,len(namelist)):
    for j in range(1,len(namelist)):
        if int(systeem.iloc[i,j]) > 0:
            W=int(systeem.iloc[i,j])
            weightlist.append(W)
            G.add_edge(namelist[i-1],namelist[j], weight= W)
        else:
            continue

plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))

pos = nx.circular_layout(G) 
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('plasma_r')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, width=1, node_color="blue", edge_cmap=cmap, with_labels=False)

labels_pos = {name:[pos_list[0], pos_list[1]-0.04] for name, pos_list in pos.items()}

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, labels_pos, font_size=40, font_family="sans-serif", font_color="#000000", font_weight="bold")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0.25)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Alright, should've done that. First time asking a question.